# Existe alguma função para calcular a linha de tendência no PL SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, pl-sql

Bom dia pessoal. Eu preciso de uma função para calcular uma linha de tendência. Eu tenho uma consulta (parte da função):

```
select round(sum(nvl(vl_indice, vl_meta))/12, 2) from (
SELECT 
  SUM (vl_indice) vl_indice, SUM (vl_meta) vl_meta
FROM
  (SELECT cd_mes, vl_indice, NULL vl_meta, dt.id_tempo,
    fi.id_multi_empresa, fi.id_setor, fi.id_indice
  FROM dbadw.fa_indice fi , dbadw.di_tempo dt ,
    dbadw.di_multi_empresa dme , dbaportal.organizacao o ,
    dbadw.di_indice di
  WHERE fi.id_tempo        = dt.id_tempo
  AND DT.CD_MES BETWEEN TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(PCD_MES),'YYYYMM'),- 11),'YYYYMM'))
                          AND PCD_MES
       AND DT.ANO = TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(PCD_MES),'YYYYMM'),'YYYY'))
  AND fi.id_multi_empresa  = dme.id_multi_empresa
  AND dme.cd_multi_empresa = NVL(o.cd_multi_empresa_mv2000, o.cd_organizacao)
  AND o.cd_organizacao     = PCD_ORG
  AND fi.id_setor         IS NULL
  AND fi.id_indice         = di.id_indice
  AND di.cd_indice         = PCD_IVM
  UNION ALL
  SELECT cd_mes, NULL vl_indice, vl_meta, dt.id_tempo,
    fm.id_multi_empresa, fm.id_setor, fm.id_indice
  FROM dbadw.fa_meta_indice fm , dbadw.di_tempo dt ,
    dbadw.di_multi_empresa dme , dbaportal.organizacao o ,
    dbadw.di_indice di
  WHERE fm.id_tempo        = dt.id_tempo
  AND DT.ANO = TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(PCD_MES),'YYYYMM'),'YYYY'))
  AND fm.id_multi_empresa  = dme.id_multi_empresa
  AND dme.cd_multi_empresa = NVL(o.cd_multi_empresa_mv2000, o.cd_organizacao)
  AND o.cd_organizacao     = PCD_ORG
  AND fm.id_setor         IS NULL
  AND fm.id_indice         = di.id_indice
  AND di.cd_indice         = PCD_IVM
  )
GROUP BY cd_mes, id_tempo, id_multi_empresa, id_setor, id_indice
ORDER BY cd_mes);
```

Onde eu tentei calcular a linha de tendência na primeira linha do select, mas não está correto. Por favor, Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: O que você quer se chama ["regressão linear"](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regress%C3%A3o_linear) e é só uma questão de fazer algumas contas matemáticas. Eu acredito que o código SQL postado acima não é necessário/relevante pra pegunta (mas a pergunta em si é boa).

Comment: @Renan Seguinte, a query acima é uma parte da função que tenho criada, ela vai buscar no banco os valores dos indices e os períodos em que se deseja verificar a linha de tendência bem como outros dados como de qual organização, empresa, setor etc pertencem..então realmente é necessária. Estive buscando e encontrei  a "regr_slope" que estou tentando saber se é adequada para este caso. Obrigado pelo aporte.

Comment: A função será realizada em cima de uma massa de dados que seu código retorna. Dessa forma, para poder ajudar, precisamos no máximo saber *o formato dos dados*, e não *a lógica que foi utilizada para obtê-los*. Dê uma olhada em outras perguntas relacionadas à regressão linear no SO, tais como [esta](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3034281/not-single-group-grouping-function-while-using-regr-slope/3034311), [esta](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4006088/pl-pgsql-array-as-input-to-an-aggregate-function) e [esta](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20490756/linear-regression-with-postgres) ;)

Comment: Ou, TL;DR: só as colunas do select é que realmente importam pro problema.

Comment: Renan, no caso os dados serão dinâmico e não uma massa de dados, poderei usar esta função? .. a cada mês que for inserido um valor (vl_indice) terei que calcular uma nova tendência.

Comment: As colunas mudam?

Comment: Tem estas functions http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions151.htm#SQLRF00696 , só preciso lembrar (ou ver) como montar a RL

Comment: VEJA TB https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/datamine.111/b28129/regress.htm

Comment: A minha consulta está retornando os seguintes dados:

CD_MES   VL_INDICE  ID_MULTI_EMPRESA
200902      1068                           1
200903      1288                           1
...
200912      1119                            1

Comment: Eu estava tentando usar a função REGR_SLOPE mas sem sucesso.

Comment: @Renan Consegui ..

  SELECT valor, mes, ((mes * SLOPE) + INTERCEPT) TENDENCIA, SLOPE, INTERCEPT 
from(
select valor, mes, ROUND(REGR_SLOPE(valor,mes) over (partition by id_multi_empresa),4)SLOPE,
ROUND(REGR_INTERCEPT(valor,mes) over (PARTITION by id_multi_empresa),4) INTERCEPT from(
...
 Agradeço a todos que deram atenção e puderam ajudar.

Comment: Poste isso aí como resposta e ganhe pontos ;)

Answer (score 1):

A solução é:

```
SELECT valor, mes, ((mes * SLOPE) + INTERCEPT) TENDENCIA, SLOPE, INTERCEPT from( 
SELECT valor, mes, ROUND(REGR_SLOPE(valor,mes) over (partition by id_multi_empresa),4)SLOPE, 
ROUND(REGR_INTERCEPT(valor,mes) over (PARTITION by id_multi_empresa),4) INTERCEPT from( -- O select inicial
```